# UITextView formatting

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I have a UITextView that shows me the following: `333, nik, 222`
I just want to separate these texts and to show me:

```
Number: 333
User: nik
Visits: 222
```

how I can do?

Comment: Please post your code if you would like help fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *longString = myTextView.text;
NSArray *array = [longString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number: %@ User: %@ Visits: %@", [array objectAtIndex:0], [array objectAtIndex:1], [array objectAtIndex:2]];
```

Comment: It's pretty easy, since you have the substrings as elements in the array you can manage them, or you can simply do this: `myTextView.text = formattedString`. If you want to separate the elements use `\n` like Ken Pespisa pointed out. ;)

Comment: I have problems :S could send the project and you notice that's what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: sure ;) send me the project to hack.3du@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextView *textView;

textView.text = @"Number: 333\nUser: nik\nVisits: 222";
```